# automatically update fields with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project, When the customer creates an account they are prompt for invoice address and shipping address.

I would like a check box, below the invoice address, which will update the shipping address with the same invoice address details, as opposed to having to enter the same address twice.

Not sure how to do it, any help would be much appreciated) an example of the check box would be

```
<div class="checkbox">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => signup.SameAddress)</div>
<div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(m => signup.SameAddress, T(Use same address as billing"))</div>
```

So far my code looks like this(below). ATM they have to enter the same details twice.

```
<article class="addresses form">
<fieldset>
    <div class="span5">
    <h2>@T("Invoice Address")</h2>

    <table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
        <colgroup>
            <col id="Col1" />
            <col id="Col2" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@T("Name")</th>
                <td>@invoiceAddress.Name.Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@T("AddressLine1")</th>
                <td>@invoiceAddress.AddressLine1.Value<</td>
            </tr>              
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>

    //insert checkbox here

    <div class="span5">
    <h2>@T("Billing Address")</h2>
    <table class="table-bordered table-striped table">
        <colgroup>
            <col id="Col1" />
            <col id="Col2" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@T("Name")</th>
                <td>@shippingAddress.Name.Value</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@T("AddressLine1")</th>
                <td>@shippingAddress.AddressLine1.Value<</td>
            </tr>               
        </thead>

    </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</article>
```

I would like to use JQuery or JS to automatically update the shipping address to the same address given for the invoice.

Thanks for any replies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something to identify your columns, i used input tags here with ids that i can select on.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test3"/>
<label for="test1">Invoice address</label><input id="test1" type="text"/>
<label for="test2">Shipping address</label><input id="test2" type="text"/>


$("#test1").on("change", function () {
    if ($("#test3").is(":checked"))
        $("#test2").val($(this).val()) ;
});
```